# Reactjs drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

Is there a plugin to achieve drag and drop like this in reactjs? I tried with react-rnd and react-beautiful-dnd.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable).
It's a simple component that can be used to make elements draggable, as shown below.

```
<Draggable>
  <div>Drag Element</div>
</Draggable>
```